# WPF and WinRT Image Source using Content Build Action

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, buildaction

I have a WinRT application and a .NET application which want to share images. I have been using portable class library and want to share as much code as possible. I also want to have only one copy of all images and use the 'Add Link' feature to add images.

My WinRT app uses a build action of 'Content' and I refer to my images using a relative path like so:
/Assets/Flags/Australia.png

I have added the images to my .NET application using add link and used the same 'Content' build action but I can't get this working. It only seems to work when I use a build action of 'Resource' and use a full path like so:
/MyProject;component/Assets/Flags/Australia.png

I have a model in my portable class libary project which contains a property returning the path to the flag image. Both applications should share this property. How can I achieve this and what build action do I use.

Comment: The "Content" build action is only used by installers to determine what files need to be copied to the target machine.  Deployment in WinRT works very differently, sharing is not possible and you have to go through the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out sharing is not possible. I ended up using seperate properties for the path to my images in WinRT and WPF.